# (Shopify) How to update my inventory message on variant change using current theme JSON + AJAX setup

Tags: json, ajax, shopify, liquid

**Background:**
I am currently helping a company move their current website to Shopify and am trying to add a custom feature to the product page. I am a web designer, not a developer so I am having trouble implementing this.

**Here is my situation:**
At this point, our theme allows us to display an "In stock & ready to ship" or an "Out of stock" message on our product page if the `variant.inventory_quantity` is great than 0 or equal to 0, respectively. In my case, I have added another option that will display a message if the following is true:
`section.settings.show_special_order_option and selected_variant.inventory_management and selected_variant.inventory_policy == 'continue' and selected_variant.inventory_quantity == 0`

In this case, `section.settings.show_special_order_option` is a checkbox option I created that when checked will [ideally] display the message. I would like this message to only be displayed if the above conditions are met, and update as each new variation is selected in the event that the conditions are not met.

**As of now, this is my code in the product-info.liquid section:**

```
{%- if selected_variant.available -%}
  {%- if selected_variant.inventory_management and selected_variant.inventory_policy == 'deny' and section.settings.low_inventory_threshold > 0 -%}
    {%- if selected_variant.inventory_quantity <= section.settings.low_inventory_threshold -%}
      <span class="product-form__inventory inventory inventory--low">{{ 'product.form.low_stock_with_quantity_count' | t: count: selected_variant.inventory_quantity }}</span>
    {%- else -%}
      <span class="product-form__inventory inventory inventory--high">{{ 'product.form.in_stock_with_quantity_count' | t: count: selected_variant.inventory_quantity }}</span>
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- elsif section.settings.show_special_order_option and selected_variant.inventory_management and selected_variant.inventory_policy == 'continue' -%}
    {%- if selected_variant.inventory_quantity == 0 -%}
      <span class="product-form__inventory inventory inventory--special-order">{{ 'product.form.no_stock_special_order' | t }}</span>
    {%- else -%}
      <span class="product-form__inventory inventory inventory--high">{{ 'product.form.in_stock' | t }}</span>
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- else -%}
    <span class="product-form__inventory inventory inventory--high">{{ 'product.form.in_stock' | t }}</span>
  {%- endif -%}              
{%- else -%}
  <span class="product-form__inventory inventory">{{ 'product.form.sold_out' | t }}</span>
{%- endif -%}
```

**And this is my JSON Script:**

```
<script type="application/json" data-product-json>
{
  "product": {{ product | json }},
  "options_with_values": {{ product.options_with_values | json }},
  "selected_variant_id": {{ selected_variant.id }}
  {%- if section.settings.show_inventory_quantity -%}
    ,"inventories": {
      {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
        {%- if variant.available -%}
          {%- if variant.inventory_management and variant.inventory_policy == 'deny' and section.settings.low_inventory_threshold > 0 -%}
            {%- if variant.inventory_quantity <= section.settings.low_inventory_threshold -%}
              {%- capture inventory_message -%}{{ 'product.form.low_stock_with_quantity_count' | t: count: variant.inventory_quantity }}{%- endcapture -%}
            {%- else -%}
              {%- capture inventory_message -%}{{ 'product.form.in_stock_with_quantity_count' | t: count: variant.inventory_quantity }}{%- endcapture -%}
            {%- endif -%}
          {%- elsif section.settings.show_special_order_option and selected_variant.inventory_management and selected_variant.inventory_policy == 'continue' -%}
            {%- if selected_variant.inventory_quantity == 0 -%}  
              {%- capture inventory_message -%}{{ 'product.form.no_stock_special_order' | t }}{%- endcapture -%}
            {%- else -%}
              {%- capture inventory_message -%}{{ 'product.form.in_stock' | t }}{%- endcapture -%}
            {%- endif -%}
          {%- else -%}
            {%- capture inventory_message -%}{{ 'product.form.in_stock' | t }}{%- endcapture -%}
          {%- endif -%}
        {%- else -%}
          {%- capture inventory_message -%}{{ 'product.form.sold_out' | t }}{%- endcapture -%}
        {%- endif -%}

        "{{ variant.id }}": {
          "inventory_management": {{ variant.inventory_management | json }},
          "inventory_policy": {{ variant.inventory_policy | json }},
          "inventory_quantity": {{ variant.inventory_quantity | json }},
          "inventory_message": {{ inventory_message | json }}
        }{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
      {%- endfor -%}
    }
  {%- endif -%}
}
</script>
```

**And finally this is the JS snippet that is executed when there is a variation change:**

```
function _updateinven(newVariant) {
    if (!this.options['showInventoryQuantity'] || !newVariant) {
      return;
    }

    var productFormInventoryElement = this.element.querySelector('.product-form__inventory'),
        variantInventoryManagement = this.variantsInventories[newVariant['id']]['inventory_management'],
        variantInventoryPolicy = this.variantsInventories[newVariant['id']]['inventory_policy'],
        variantInventoryQuantity = this.variantsInventories[newVariant['id']]['inventory_quantity'],
        variantInventoryMessage = this.variantsInventories[newVariant['id']]['inventory_message'];

    productFormInventoryElement.classList.remove('inventory--high');
    productFormInventoryElement.classList.remove('inventory--low');
    productFormInventoryElement.classList.remove('inventory--special-order');

    if (newVariant['available']) {
      if (null !== variantInventoryManagement && variantInventoryPolicy === 'deny' && this.options['lowInventoryThreshold'] > 0) {
        if (variantInventoryQuantity <= this.options['lowInventoryThreshold']) {
          productFormInventoryElement.classList.add('inventory--low');
        } else {
          productFormInventoryElement.classList.add('inventory--high');
        }
      } else if (variantInventoryQuantity === 0) {
        productFormInventoryElement.classList.add('inventory--special-order');
      } else {
        productFormInventoryElement.classList.add('inventory--high');
      }
    }

    // We also need to update the stock countdown if setup
    var stockCountdown = this.element.querySelector('.inventory-bar');

    if (stockCountdown) {
      var stockCountdownProgress = Math.min(Math.max(variantInventoryQuantity / parseInt(stockCountdown.getAttribute('data-stock-countdown-max')) * 100.0, 0), 100);

      stockCountdown.classList.toggle('inventory-bar--hidden', stockCountdownProgress === 0);
      stockCountdown.firstElementChild.style.width = stockCountdownProgress + '%';
    }

    productFormInventoryElement.innerHTML = variantInventoryMessage;
  }
```

**How the function currently works:**
As of now, when clicking on a product that is available and has inventory greater than 0, the "In stock & ready to ship" message appears in green (the class 'inventory--high' is what makes it green). When clicking on another variation that is out of stock but set to 'Continue selling when out of stock' the message stays the same, but the color changes to orange (the class 'inventory--special-order' is what makes it orange).

**What appears to be the problem:**
I have narrowed this problem down to the liquid function and/or JSON script. When viewing the page source, I look at the computed JSON script and it is displaying the same message for all variations when it should be displaying unique messages depending on the conditions set forth. (In other words, every variation in the JSON script has the same inventory message of "In stock & ready to ship" or "Special order: this product will take 7-10 days to arrive" even if there multiple variations in stock and multiple not in stock but able to continue selling).

**My question:**
Assuming I have provided all the necessary information, I am in need of some guidance as to correct my function to display the proper inventory message for each variation as the user selects different variations. Could someone please help me solve this problem? Please let me know if you need any additional information from me.